# Create a .txt file and then delete it

Tags: python, python-3.x

Program: Pycharm
python 3.6
I would like to Create a .txt file and then delete it...
I already tried FileName.close() and FileName.flush()

I need to stop the program and rerun it to recognize the file and be able to delete it.

Here is my code:

```
import os 
temp = input("Please Enter File Name to create: ")
FileName = open(temp,"w+")
print("File Created!"+"\n")

temp = input("Please Enter File Name to delete: ")
os.remove(temp)
print("File Removed!)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpP5v.png)

Comment: There are nothing wrong on your code (if you include FileName.close() before to os.remove ) This code creates a file and then deletes it ( if name match )

Comment: Add the error traceback as well

Comment: I added a picture of the error

Comment: Not sure if that's your actual use case, but if you want to create a temporary file and delete it at the end of the program's execution, there's a [modue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) for that.

Comment: FileName should be file_name in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what danihp means:

```
import os 
temp = input("Please Enter File Name to create: ")
FileName = open(temp,"w+")
print("File Created!"+"\n")
FileName.close() # <---

temp = input("Please Enter File Name to delete: ")
os.remove(temp)
print("File Removed!)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a tempfile module in the standard library. You should not be doing this yourself with os method calls.

The tempfile module will respect the operating system's native methods of creating temp files and will clean up the temp file automatically even if an exception happens.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Look at TempFile and NamedTemporaryFile.

Also os method calls are pretty much depreciated in favor of pathlib. It provides a much cleaner OO syntax.